# How can I have a tabbed widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a page with a pie chart which represents different values. What I want to do is under the pie chart have a widget that works like a scaffold with a Tabbar which has different widgets, in my case a few Listviews I already finished that represent all the different slices in the piechart. As you click on the different Tabs, it switches to the according list, like a tabpage.

I didn't figure out how to do this, so if there is no premade way I think I will just make my own widget for this, but before I resort to this I wanted to ask if there already is a widget/method for this or someone else had this issue before.

I just drew up something with balsamiq real quick:

[image]

all is done but the tabs, that don't need to look like that by the way

the code i need to enter this widget into is like:

```dart
class _ListWithTabsState extends State<ListWithTabs> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //here i need the widget
  }
}

class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomAppPage(
       widget: Column(
          children: [
             PieChartClass(data),
             ListWithTabs(data),
         ],
      ),
   ),
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are widgets for this as described here:

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs

You basically use a `DefaultTabController`, `TabBar`, `Tab` and `TabBarView` and it will automatically animate between the different tabs. Or you can use your own controller if you want even more control.

Full example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TabBarDemo());
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a class in which i build my widget, it is like `class ListViewWidget extends StateFullWidget{}` and a state, and i tried to copy/paste the Defaulttabcontroller into the return of the build, HOWEVER that gave me a ''RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout." what went wrong?

Comment: @MaritnGe Try wrapping the controller in a `Container`.

Comment: @MaritnGe Or the list itself, if you have a list inside of a tab.

Comment: At the moment I just have your code with no list yet, and wrapping the controller in a container nothing happens. I put it if you look at the sample code to the commented spot

Comment: @MaritnGe What if you wrap `ListWithTabs(data)` with `Expanded`? Like `Expanded(child: ListWithTabs(data),)`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, that did it! the expanded. Thank you again!

Comment: @MaritnGe Perfect. Don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful.